# Deleting edges in duplicate graph deletes edges in original graph

Tags: python, igraph

I create a graph and store it in a new temp variable

```
gg = Graph()
gg.add_vertices(6)
gg.add_edges([(0,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,3)])
temp=gg
```

When I print both the graphs, I get the same output:

```
print gg
print temp

Output:
IGRAPH U--- 6 7 --
+ edges:
0--1 1--2 0--2 2--3 3--4 4--5 3--5
IGRAPH U--- 6 7 --
+ edges:
0--1 1--2 0--2 2--3 3--4 4--5 3--5
```

I then delete edges from the temp graph and print both graphs again but it looks like the edges have been deleted from the original gg graph as well.

```
temp.delete_edges([1,2])
print gg
print temp

Output:
IGRAPH U--- 6 5 --
+ edges:
0--1 2--3 3--4 4--5 3--5
IGRAPH U--- 6 5 --
+ edges:
0--1 2--3 3--4 4--5 3--5
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is there some nuance to how Python handles graphs that I am missing because this does not seem to happen in R. Thanks!

Comment: `temp` is just another reference to the same graph; it's not a copy.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.